# Python スクリプトの実行時に "IndexError: pop from empty list" エラー

Tags: python

`https://qiita.com/kansiho/items/2b868851b12f0fc0cb24` (編注: 投稿は削除済み)

Qiita の @kanshio さんのプログラムを自分の環境で再現したいと考えています。

環境： Ubuntu 16.04 TLS
使用言語： Python 3.6.0

1形態ごとのリストを返すプログラムを写して稼働させました。

```
def get_m_lines(file) : # 解析結果のファイルを読み込む
    f = open(file, 'r') # 解析結果のファイルを開く
    m_lines = f.read().split('\n') # 読み込んで，改行で分割

    # m_linesの最後2つの要素はEOSと空白なのでカットしておく
    m_lines.pop(-1)
    m_lines.pop(-1)

    f.close()
    return m_lines # 結果（１形態素毎の情報のリスト）を返す

mlines = get_m_lines('okurimono_m.txt')
```

その後`file`を作成したtxtファイル名に変更し実行したところ、
`IndexError: pop from empty list`と表示されました。

fileの中身は空ではないため、Stack Overflow の記事を参照しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048405/indexerror-pop-from-empty-list

ファイルの中身がない可能性が指摘されているので、txtファイルの中身をエディタで確認しましたが、中身があるのでfileには問題がないと思います。

どうすれば動くようになるでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: とりあえず `print(m_lines)` とかを適宜仕込むのとかがおすすめです．

Comment: `IndexError: pop from empty list` の前後の表示も含めてどの行でエラーが発生したかわかると回答しやすいと思います。